# How to create a circle that fits Google maps view-port?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a circle on Google map but the problem is: 
I want the circle to fit view-port (map area) either height or width wise (whichever is smaller).

Actually, I want to implement radius search so I find this a better way. Please let me know if I am doing it wrong or any other better way to do it. I am using Google maps API v3.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, here is a jsbin code sample link: http://jsbin.com/kalazeyomi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question itself, not (only) as a link an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a circle that fits the shortest segment (to canvas top or left). You need to include the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to compute the distances.

```
// Get map bounds
var bounds = map.getBounds();

// Find map top border & distance to center
var mapTop = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), myLatLng.lng());
var distanceToTop = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLatLng, mapTop);

// Find map left border & distance to center
var mapLeft = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng.lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng());
var distanceToLeft = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myLatLng, mapLeft);

// Get shortest length
var radius = distanceToTop < distanceToLeft ? distanceToTop : distanceToLeft;

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    editable: true,
    map: map,
    center: myLatLng,
    radius: radius
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/qftnk27j/)</kbd>

Comment: does it calculate radius in "meters"?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance). *Distance results are expressed in meters.* And so does the radius of a [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions).